# How to correctly define deployment spec file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have to create deployment spec file that will:

- Launch **3** replicas of the **nginx** image with label **all_label**
- Deployment name **star_deploy**

Save a copy of this spec file to **deployment_spec.yaml** or **json**. After I am done, I need to clean up(delete) any new Kubernetes object which I produced during this task. Based on this task, I do not know how to solve this task. Should I create the deployment and after that, use command

```
kubectl get deployment star_deploy -o yaml > deployment_spec.yaml
```

or during creation, use command

```
kubectl create deployment star_deploy --image=nginx  --dry-run -o yaml > deployment_spec.yaml
```

What do you think is best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advocate usage of `--dry-run` option to create a base yaml file and edit it to make necessary changes and then use `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml` to actaually create the resources.

Once the task is done you can clean up using `kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml`

This is following the declarative methodology which makes it easier to define deployments (or any resource) and manage their lifecycle through CI/CD or GitOps.

Comment: I understand but should not i run command kubectl delete deployment  star_deploy after all of that ?

Comment: @O.Man  to delete deployment ```kubectl delete deployment star_deploy```

Comment: I would prefer declarative approach ..which is `kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml` vs imperative approach of `kubectl delete deploy star_deploy`

Comment: Ok guys i see it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Dry run is always good because it give only necessary output without any garbage value like revision number, creationTimestmp etc. And this will give you clean production grade yaml file for deployment. Later you can use this to create daemonsets etc.

```
kubectl create deployment star_deploy --image=nginx  --dry-run=client -o yaml > deployment_spec.yaml
```

Note: Always run dry-run as client

Once you generate the yaml then apply this yaml to create deployment by using

```
kubectl apply -f deployment_spec.yaml
```

to scale the pods for that deployment you don'even need to edit yaml file.

```
kubectl scale deployment star_deploy --replicas=3
```

and to delete the created deployment you can use

```
kubectl delete deployment star_deploy
```